# Print enum values in between specified characters

Tags: java

I have an enum with values {EVEN, ODD, BUZZ, DUCK, PALINDROMIC, GAPFUL, SPY, SQUARE, SUNNY} and am trying to iterate over them and print them in the format [BUZZ, DUCK, PALINDROMIC, GAPFUL, SPY, EVEN, ODD, SQUARE, SUNNY].

I've only succeeded in printing them separated by comma but am trying to find a way to define inclosing characters, in this case, square brackets in the format specified above.

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(Property.values()).map(Property::name).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.joining(",")` → `.joining(", ", "[", "]")`

Comment: This also works for the output format you specified: `Arrays.toString(Property.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of [`joining(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) and provide a prefix and suffix as follows:

```
Arrays.stream(Property.values()).map(Property::name).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for streams. Just convert the values array to list:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Property.values()));
```

Comment: This won't work if we need to specify diffrent delimiter, suffix and prefix characters.

Comment: @lkatiforis OP has shared the desired output and didn't mentioned to need a solution where they can specify delimiters, prefixes or suffixes. In such a case why not KISS.